# Density of non-algebraic leaves in the characteristic foliation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, foliations

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold equipped with a holomorphic symplectic form $\omega$. Let $D$ be a smooth divisor on $X$. At each point of $D$, the restriction of $\omega$ to $D$ has one-dimensional kernel. This gives a non-singular foliation $F$ on $D$.

Is it true that if there exists at least one non-algebraic leaf then the union of all non-algebraic leaves can not be contained in a closed subvariey of $D$?

Comment: What do you mean by an algebraic leaf? You did not stipulate that $X$ is an algebraic variety.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie.  That  is a good point, but probably the OP just means that there is a compact leaf.  Every compact leaf is a closed analytic subvariety of complex dimension $1$.  A compact complex analytic variety of dimension $1$ is automatically the underlying complex analytic variety of a (unique) complex algebraic variety (also of dimension $1$).

Comment: @Jason Starr. That's what I more or less assumed they meant, too, And conversely of course if $X$ (hence $D$) is algebraic then any leaf that is an algebraic subvariety is compact.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Yes, $X$ is not assumed to be algebraic but as Jason Starr pointed out, for one-dimensional manifolds the algebraicity is equivalent to the compactness, so you are right about what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

For a foliation on a projective manifold $Y$, the set of points belonging to invariant subschemes with a given Hilbert polynomial is a Zariski closed subset of $Y$. Therefore the set of algebraic leaves is a countable union of Zariski closed subsets. In particular, the set of points belonging to nonalgebraic leaves, if not empty, is dense both in Zariski and in Euclidean topology.

If the ambient is compact Kahler then the analogue statement probably holds true. Without the Kahler assumption I am not sure what can be said.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate or give a reference about the Kahler case?